# how to remove active effect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove the active effect of my nav bar in html by using js, and here is my html code

```
<nav>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" id="a"><a href="#">a</a>
            </li>   
            <li role="presentation" id="b"><a href="#">b</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" id="c"><a href="#">c</a>
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and my js code goes here

```
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    var b = document.getElementById('b');
    var c = document.getElementById('c');

    a.addEventListener('click',active);
    b.addEventListener('click',active);
    c.addEventListener('click',active);

    function active(){
        this.classList.add('active');
        if(this.className == 'active'){
              this.className = '';
         }
    }
```

the problem is when I click those nav bars, I want it to deactivate other bars which have been clicked, and somehow the active status remains on other bars. I'll be more than thankful if someone could point me out my mistake and teach me how to achieve my goal here

Comment: Unrelated, but use `classList.contains` instead of `className ==` as it will work in the case where multiple class names are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blindly setting the `active` class, but then removing it (as `add('active')` will cause `className == 'active'`).

Additionally your `this` value is probably pointing to the wrong object (likely `window`) instead of the clicked element.

Rather than using `this`, you should use `eventArgs.currentTarget` so you know exactly which element you're targeting (`currentTarget` refers to the element that the event-listener was added to).

Like so:

```
function onListItemClicked(e) {
    var li = e.currentTarget;

    // Remove 'active' from all other <li> elements first, before setting it on the desired element:
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul.nav.nav-tabs li');
    for( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ ) {
        lis[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    // Add 'active' to only the desired element:
    li.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: You could even improve the selector to just include elements that actually have the active class to avoid a bit of work: `document.querySelectorAll('ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active')`

Comment: thank you, you solve the problem that troubles me for two days